# Why don't the timestamps in Java and Wireshark match?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, time, wireshark

In Java I am getting a timestamp this way:

```
Date date= new java.util.Date();
return (new Timestamp(date.getTime())).toString();
```

Output is for example:

```
Start - 2015-02-16 13:59:41.427
```

Then I write a packet to a socket.

However, in Wireshark, the first packet is dated as follows:

```
62  2015-02-16 13:59:41.421115000   ...
```

What???

Ok, I don't want someone to tell me the timestamps are off.  Is there a way to change the Java code to make it produce timesstamp that are more in line with Wireshark?

Thanks

EDIT: Code Requested

```
System.err.println("Start - "+currentTimestamp());
int sent = socketChannelOut.write(data);
```

Comment: do you take the timestamp before you write to the socket?

Comment: Is Wireshark known to listen to some NTP going on?

Comment: @Zhedar Yes. The order it timestamp in java, send packet, and then timestamp in wireshark.

Comment: @Zhedar I would expect a small delay after writing to the socket, before the packet showed up in Wireshark.

Comment: I think what you are seeing is perfectly normal. It takes time to push a packet down the network stack. All you are seeing is the time difference between when you send the packet and when you request the system time in java.

Comment: @laune It appears to not be using  NTP.  It is using the WinPcap driver http://wiki.wireshark.org/Timestamps.

Comment: @bhspencer I was expecting a small delay.  However, if you notice, the timestamp is wireshark is actually before the timestamp in java.

Comment: Could you show more of your code. Where do you write to the socket with respect to the call creating the new Date object?

Comment: @bhspencer I write to the socket after the timestamp.  Adding more code.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is simply down to the to the accuracy of how your system measures time. To quote from the java doc:

> "Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of
>   time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the
>   value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger.
>   For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of
>   milliseconds."

Since the discrepancy you are seeing is 0.005885s and this is less than 10ms I do not think there is an expectation that a comparison with another process measuring time will be accurate to less than 10ms granularity.  Which is to say this time 41.427 that you got from Java is really 41.427 +/-10ms

Comment: Also, add that Timestamp is constructed from a (rounded?) milliseconds value (Date.getTime()), whereas Wireshark may call gettimeofday returning microseconds.